# Select any element by class - xpath

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How can I select any element by class/name using xpath?

```
var nodeByClass = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//[@class='class_name']");
var nodeName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//[@name='element_name']");
```

I got a exception

```
The expression must be evaluated for a set of nodes.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an * to the xpath. The * means you want to select any element.

```
var nodeByClass = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='class_name']");
var nodeName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@name='element_name']");
```

Answer (score 0):

`var nodeByClass = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='class_name']");
var nodeName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@name='element_name']");`

Since you did not specify the element tag, * would highlight all of the element in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a location step after the `//`, as the predicate on its own is not allowed.

```
var nodeByClass = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='class_name']");
var nodeName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@name='element_name']");
```

short-hand for:

```
var nodeByClass = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//self::node()[@class='class_name']");
var nodeName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//self::node()[@name='element_name']");
```